# How Do You Achieve Realistic Spinning for Exhaust Fans?

Tags: modeling

I've been struggling for 2 days now trying to figure out how to approach this situation. I wanted to spin an exhaust fan that I modeled in 2.8 but the results is just not right.

My goal is to have a 10 second animation of a computer chassis where the exhaust fan is actually spinning at full speed.

Although I was able to spin it, it's not as fast (not realistic) as the GIF image below.

Is there like a filter to fake it?

Thanks

PS: how can i attach more than 1 image in a question? :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways which you can fake the effect for a fan blade spinning fast. One would be to use or create a texture which has the original appearance of a fast spinning blade and then jut animate that.

Another way and more than likely what you are looking for is to use a vector blur node in compositing to add the blur effect to the blades.

Here is a link for how this can be used.

[Vector (Motion) Blur Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/filter/vector_blur.html)

You can also use the motion blur effect located in the render tab to create motion blur for the animation. Here is an example for how something like this can be done.

[Blender Tutorial - How to Create Motion Blur For The Wheels](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eI5vxpjoW3M)

Comment: @natahan rivera thanks buddy...

I did the MOTION BLUR tab already but not enough. ill try this VECTOR NODE first :)

Comment: Managed to add motion using VECTOR BLUR node but it's not enough.

PS: how can I post additional images on repliese?

Comment: Update:

Vector Blur is not the solution I realized. It blurs the entire scene including the objects that aren't spinning but moving from one location to another :)

I just want the blur to affect the SPINNING FANS ....

STILL SEARCHING!